# Android Google Drive Api share files across devices and accounts

Tags: android, scope, share, google-drive-android-api, unauthorized

I'am using the **Google Drive Android API**. My application is synchronizing files to a google drive folder. This is working properly.
Additionally, I want to share those folders and files with other users. Unfortunately from another device and account in the same app I can only access files/folders which I have picked through the Files/Folder pickers (see https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo)

My GoogleApiClient is getting the scope: `Drive.SCOPE_FILE`. So description says:

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app

Since I am using the same app on another device with a different account shouldn't I be able to access those files? Btw with the same account on another device this is working.

Is there any other solution? I've already checked the REST API but I am afraid this would make the whole code much more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone who is interested in a solution:

- I found no way to sync shared files with the google android native API. (besides the file picker)
- In case you want to do so you have to use the google drive rest API.

A little advantage for this solution. I think the java rest API is anyway much more suited for this kind of work. Code gets in that way much more readable.

Comment: can we download file from appdata folder

Answer (score 0):

You just need to authorized the user. Take note that in every request your application sends to the Drive API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google. You must impliment [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported.

All requests to the Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

The details of the authorization process, or "flow," for OAuth 2.0 vary somewhat depending on what kind of application you're writing. The following general process applies to all application types:

- When you create your application, you register it using the Google API Console. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
- Activate the Drive API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
- When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
- Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
- If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
- Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
- If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

Some flows include additional steps, such as using refresh tokens to acquire new access tokens. For detailed information about flows for various types of applications, see Google's [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) documentation.

**Scope:**
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` - Per-file access to files created or opened by the app

[Full access to all files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#requesting_full_drive_scope_for_an_app) in the user's Drive `(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)` may be necessary for some apps. An app designed to sync files, for instance, needs this level of access to Drive. Apps with special needs related to listing or reorganizing files might need full scope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably you are referring to the google drive rest api. I am currently using the android google drive native api. All request are working properly on one device. If I am using another device with the same account it is still working properly. Only when I am sharing data with another account it is not working.